# Puzzling memory behavior in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell

I am trying to compare the performance of Haskell lists and arrays and run into a strange behavior.
 I observed that if I create a array and then print it it takes 'x' MB of memory but if I convert the array into a list using the 'elems' function and then print it takes memory less than 'x'. 
 Isn't the 'elems' function supposed to create a new list from the array? Shouldn't it take more space than the function which does not create the list?
 I am using the -O2 and -fspec-constr optimizing flags. I am also using the -p flag to profile the functions.

This is the code without intermediate list,

```
fun  n = runST $  do
      final_soln <- newArray_ ((1,1), (n, (10 ^ n))) :: ST s ((STUArray s)  (Int,Int) Int)
      U.unsafeFreeze final_soln

main = do 
    [n] <- getArgs
    {-#  SCC "file-writing" #-} (writeFile "cprod-starray-creation.txt"  $ show $ fun (read n))
```

This is the code with the intermediate list,

```
fun :: Int -> UArray (Int,Int) Int
fun  n = runST $  do
      final_soln <- newArray_ ((1,1), (n, (10 ^ n))) :: ST s ((STUArray s)  (Int,Int) Int)
      U.unsafeFreeze final_soln

main = do 
    [n] <- getArgs
    {-#  SCC "file-writing" #-} (writeFile "cprod-starray-creation.txt"  $ show $ elems $ fun (read n))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give the complete code with import statements that we can easily copy’n’paste’n’run it. Also, ghc the version number might be useful.

Comment: Also, your first code need the type signature of ```fun``` to compile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a lack of lazyness in the first variant, and it is not your fault. Comparing the profiling output (`+RTS -hd`) of a run with parameter 6 gives the first hint:

[image: Profiling of the first code]

is the profiling output of the first code, while

[image: Profiling of the first code]

is the result of the second code. The array itself (`ARR_WORDS`) takes the same space in both. You also see that the first code produces a large list (recognizable by the `:` constructor) of `Int` constructors (which happen to have the name `Int#`).

Now this cannot be the final String as printed, as that would be `Char`s then (with constructor `C#`). It can also not be the list of elements in the array, as the array contains zeros and the garbage collector has a cache of small `Int`s (in the range [-16,16]) that it would use instead of allocating (or actually instead of copying) a new constructor.

Also note that it takes about 24MB for the `:` constructors and 16MB for the `I#` constructors. Knowing that the former require 3 words and the latter 2 words, and that one word on my machine is 8 bytes long, we find that the list is 100000=10^6 elements long. So a very good candidate is the range of the second index parameter.

So where is this array? Let us trace your call to `show`:

```
showsIArray :: (IArray a e, Ix i, Show i, Show e) => Int -> a i e -> ShowS
showsIArray p a =
    showParen (p > 9) $
    showString "array " .
    shows (bounds a) .
    showChar ' ' .
    shows (assocs a)
```

(Code from [Data.Array.Base](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Array-Base.html)). Clearly, the culprit must be in the `assocs` call, so here is the source for that:

```
assocs :: (IArray a e, Ix i) => a i e -> [(i, e)]
assocs arr = case bounds arr of
    (l,u) -> [(i, arr ! i) | i <- range (l,u)]
```

Since we are looking for the a list of indices, the `range` call looks suspicious enough. For that we have to look into the source of [GHC.Arr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Arr.html) (which unfortunately haddock messed up):

```
instance (Ix a, Ix b) => Ix (a, b) where
    range ((l1,l2),(u1,u2)) = [ (i1,i2) | i1 <- range (l1,u1), i2 <- range (l2,u2) ]
```

And now we have found the culprit: Here, `range (l2,u2)` will evaluate to the list `[1..1000000]` and *shared* for every step in the first component of the index.

Now I guess you’ll be curious in trying to put `assocs` instead of `elems` in the second code, and expecting the space leak there. But you won’t see it. The reason is that `show` is not inlined, but `assocs` itself gets inlined, and then also a whole bunch of other functions, including `range` effectively avoiding the sharing. You can see that (somewhat) by passing `-ddump-rule-firings` to GHC:

```
$ ghc --make -O2 -fspec-constr -ddump-rule-firings -fforce-recomp code2.hs -prof -fprof-auto
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( code2.hs, code2.o )
Rule fired: SPEC GHC.Arr.$fIx(,)
Rule fired: unpack
Rule fired: Class op fail
Rule fired: unpack
Rule fired: Class op show
Rule fired: Class op newArray_
Rule fired: unsafeFreeze/STUArray
Rule fired: Class op >>=
Rule fired: Class op >>=
Rule fired: Class op showList
Rule fired: Class op rangeSize
Rule fired: Class op rangeSize
Rule fired: Class op bounds
Rule fired: Class op bounds
Rule fired: Class op numElements
Rule fired: Class op index
Rule fired: Class op unsafeAt
Rule fired: Class op range
Rule fired: fold/build
Rule fired: SPEC GHC.Real.^
Rule fired: unpack-list
Rule fired: foldr/app
Rule fired: unpack-append
Rule fired: foldr/app
Rule fired: unpack-append
Rule fired: >#
Rule fired: >#
Rule fired: x# <=# x#
Rule fired: x# -# x#
Rule fired: 0# *# x#
Rule fired: 0# +# x#
Linking code2 ...
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how to prevent this issue in the range code. I guess my dup operator (http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2017) would do wonders here :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Joachim. I am sorry I did not post the full code in my earlier post.

Comment: Hi Joachim, Hope you remember me. I am the PhD student with Prof.Sanyal. Its been a long time. I had to post this on stack overflow as I didn't have your email id. Hope you are doing well.
- Prasanna

Comment: Heh, indeed. I thought the name has a familiar ring. Nice to hear from you. My mail address in on my stackoverflow profile page.